# Start Workflow programmatically from timer job

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, workflow

I want to start a SharePoint 2013 workflow from C# code. The code is executed when a timer job runs.

I have the following snippen which works perfectly in "normal" sharepoint code but not when the timer is executed:

```
                                var workflowServiceManager = new WorkflowServicesManager(web);
                                var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();


                                //get all workflows associated with the list
                                var subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(list.ID);

                                //run all workflows associated with the list
                                foreach (var workflowSubscription in subscriptions)
                                {
                                    //initiation parameters
                                    var inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                                    workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService().StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSubscription, item.ID, inputParameters);
                                }
```

I read somewhere that the problem could be that the web i have is elevated so i impersonated an other user but I get an AuthorizationException.

If I use the elevated web I do not get an error message. The debuger just disconnects.

has anybody had this problem and solved it?

best regards
Alex

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint Timer job runs Under"SharePoint farm account".

The timer service runs as the farm service account specified in the COnfiguration Wizard. You can verify this in Windows Services.

RunWithElevatedPrivileges only works if the current thread is using impersonation, i.e. IIS. Used in other code (timer jobs, console applications, workflow, etc.) it will have no effect.

Comment: Yes I know. The web I have in the code is running under "SHAREPOINT/system account" but if i try to enumerate the subscriptions with this web the thread aborts. I also tried impersonating a normal user and create a new web, which is working, but then i get an unauthorized exception even if the code works with the same "impersonated" user when i run it outside of a timerjob

Comment: under which user your sharepoint timer service runs?

Comment: the timer service runs under the system account. accoring to this blog: http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.co.at/2013/05/programmatically-start-sharepoint-2013.html the code won't work with the system account. this is why i impersonated a normal user. when i check the "currentUser" of the impersonated web i get a normal user but then i get the exception. running this code with the system account aborts the code execution without an exception

Answer (score 0):

You should open your web with specific user token. It works great for me in timer job task:

```
public override void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)
    {
        SPWebApplication webapp = this.Parent as SPWebApplication;
        SPSite _site = webapp.Sites["sites/site/"];
        SPWeb _web = _site.OpenWeb();
        SPUser user = _web.AllUsers[@"i:0#.w|domain\user_name"];
        SPUserToken token = user.UserToken;

        // Obtain a reference to the maagers site collection.
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_site.Url, token))
        {
            //Obtain a reference to the managers site.
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["List1"];
                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
                string workflowName = "MyWorkflowName";

                foreach (SPListItem item in items)
                {
                    var workflowServiceManager = new Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager(item.Web);
                    var workflowSubscriptionService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService();

                    // Get all workflows associated with the list
                    var subscriptions = workflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(item.ParentList.ID);

                    // Run all workflows associated with the list
                    foreach (var workflowSubscription in subscriptions)
                    {
                        if (workflowSubscription.Name.Equals(workflowName))
                        {
                            // Pass in any initiation parameters
                            var inputParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                            workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService().StartWorkflowOnListItem(workflowSubscription, item.ID, inputParameters);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And also `domain\user_name` must have non empty `User name` field in web user profile:

```
https://mysharepoint/sites/site/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?id={id}&Force=True
```